# How to find button without name using splinter

Tags: python, splinter

I have this html:

```
<a role="button" title="Datei hinzufügen" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" href="#" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1622033800890_3429">
                    <i class="icon fa fa-file-o fa-fw " aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
```

How do I find it using Splinter?
I have already tried `find_by_text`, `find_by_name`,`find_by_id`, `find_by_xpath`(by just copying xpath from browser console), none of these worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figuered it out, I had to use the underlying selenium driver

```
browser.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn-secondary").click()
```

that way it worked